# VFD interference with microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, emc, interference, vfd

I’m doing a project that requires the control of a VFD (variable frequency drive) that powers a motor by using a microcontroller to send the signals.

When the VFD is powering the motor, there is a lot of interference on the microcontroller and the LCD which is also connected to the microcontroller.

How can I reduce or eliminate the interference?

Answer (score 1):

A common thing that is neglected when using a VFD is the need for a proper shielded cable between the VFD and motor. This is critical. I’ve seen many installations where unshielded cable has been used and whilst the VFD and motor work fine, the interference is excessive.
Companies like Lapp produce shielded cable especially for VFD applications. Properly installed, it will reduce interference significantly.

I’d suggest you follow this path first. As well, follow all the recommendations of the VFD manufacturer. In my experience this has resolved interference problems. If they persist, you will need to identify where the interference is coming from. I’ve used an oscilloscope and a crude ‘sniffer’ probe comprised of a few loops of wire that you can move around to various points and measure the relative level of interference.

Another note, keep your microcontroller wiring away from the mains and motor wiring. It may require shielding as well.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have just got a new properly shielded cable for between mains and the VFD and between the VFD and the motor. Also put a mains filter in and mounted the VFD in a steel enclosure. The microcontroller sends AVI signal to control the speed, ACM is connected to microcontroller ground as well as DCM. A button creates a short between DCM and MI1 to start the motor. Will do some testing tomorrow and let you know if the shielding worked.